# Es necesario cerrar los hilos al iniciarlos? Thread!

Tags: java, android-studio, hilos

soy nuevo en las cosas de Android, hace poco descubrí que puedo crear hilos para hacer cosas en segundo plano y no usar el hilo principal.
El siguiente código es uno que hice para poder subir una imagen ya sea de la cámara o de la galería a un servidor.

- Pueden decirme si es correcto?
- Necesito cerrar el hilo al terminar la subida o se cierra automáticamente?
- Harían algo para mejorar el código?

  ```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(foto.getDrawable() == null){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(layout_admin.this, "Debe Seleccionar una Imágen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }else {
                try {
                    Bitmap imagenFinal = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,780,1380,false);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    imagenFinal.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos2);
                    byte[] fobytes2 = baos2.toByteArray();
                    PreparedStatement pat = conexionBD().prepareStatement("insert into Images(foto) values(?)");
                    pat.setString(1, Base64.encodeToString(fobytes2, Base64.DEFAULT));
                    pat.executeUpdate();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            foto.setImageResource(0);
                            Toast.makeText(layout_admin.this, "La Imágen se subió!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
  ```

y en el caso de que necesite cerrarlos, como puedo hacerlo? no encontré mucho de éso.
Éso sería todo muchas gracias!

Comment: Los hilos son muy necesarios, pero hay que saber como usarlos. Si vas a crear un hilo cada que vayas a realizar algun proceso que requieras de forma asincrona, preocupate por cerrarlo, de lo contrario vas a terminar haciendo que el servidor o el equipo donde tengas montado el projecto, en este caso para android en el dispositivo movil, harás que colapse

Comment: @jGomez Como se puede cerrar un hilo en Android?